# Question on methods of determining positivity/negativity of infinity in RH/LH limits

Tags: calculus, limits

When taking the right or left hand limit, if direct substitution results in (non zero #)/zero, my prof today asked the question: "'generally speaking', how would we know if it is + infinity or -infinity?"

If this "generally speaking" refers to method of determining the +/- of infinity, what are some methods that are not applicable in determining the direction of the infinite asymptote?

Is there a situation where methods such as plugging in numbers close to x (for example 3.0000001 for lim f(x) --> 3+ when f(x)'s denominator is x - 3 or 3 - x (in its simplest form)) will not be helpful in determining the +/- of the asymptote?

Thanks for help!!:)

Comment: Give $x \sin(\pi/x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ a try...

Comment: Rather than "plugging in numbers", I would think "determine where the function in the numerator is positive/negative, and where the function in the denominator is positive/negative". Determining where a function is positive or negative or zero is a fundamental algebraic skill, and it also does everything we need to solve the question asked.